# key vault references in a staging deployment slot

Tags: azure, staging, azure-appservice

I have a function app in which I added a new staging deployment slot as follows:

[image]

Looking at the configuration of staging slot, I see that the key vault references are errored out:

[image]

[image]

Why is that?

UPDATE:

On enabling Identity, I now see a different error:

[image]

Comment: @RajkumarMamidiChettu-MT Could you please answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71789955/deployment-slots-in-azure-functionapp Thank you!